# GCM-Cordova for Android

Tags: android, cordova, google-cloud-messaging

Pls I am using  Holly Schinsky's tutorial on GCM-Cordova ([see the tutorial here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/phonegap/articles/android-push-notifications-with-phonegap.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader_5)) to create GCM phonegap Android app. I have installed it successfully, but I do not know how to write codes to display the REGID number returned from Google gcm on my index.html page.

2. I also need help on how to write codes to send the REGID to my server from the app.

Thanks for your anticipated help.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin will call the provided GCM-Success function if the device was registered successfully.

```
window.GCM.register("[your_sender_id]", "GCM_Event", function(result){
  //write regid to scope
  $scope.regid = result.regid;

  //use some REST API to write the regid to server
  $http.post(....);
}, function(error){
  //error handling
})
```

Comment: No, you need to implement RESTful Webservices on your backend and then use `$http` or `$resource` to send data.